# how to add extentions in Fireforx web driver using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to add canvasBlocker extension to Firefox webDriver, I had  download the extension in a xpi format but i did not understand why this code not working

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extension="canvasblocker-0.4.5b-an+fx.xpi")

profile.set_preference("extensions.canvasblocker.currentVersion","0.4.5b")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,executable_path="/home/user/Bureau/doc/geckodriver")
```

Error -

> File "scraping.py", line 31, in 
>       profile.add_extension(extension="canvasblocker-0.4.5b-an+fx.xpi")   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py",
>   line 95, in add_extension
>       self._install_extension(extension)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py",
>   line 274, in _install_extension
>       addon_details = self._addon_details(addon)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py",
>   line 351, in _addon_details
>       raise AddonFormatError(str(e), sys.exc_info()[2]) selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.AddonFormatError: ("[Errno
>   2] No such file or directory:
>   '/tmp/tmp92ife_.canvasblocker-0.4.5b-an+fx.xpi/install.rdf'",
>   )

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the reason for the error and a workaround here:
[USING FIREFOX WEBEXTENSIONS WITH SELENIUM](https://intoli.com/blog/firefox-extensions-with-selenium/)